# how to get query output as a single table - aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

Thank you in advance.

I am trying to get the result in a single table - specifically to get instance id, status and output.

```
aws ssm list-command-invocations --command-id "<commandid>" --details  --query "CommandInvocations[].{Instancename:InstanceId,status:CommandPlugins[].Status,Output:CommandPlugins[].Output}" --output table
```

Result I am getting is below.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                           ListCommandInvocations                            |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                Instancename                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  i-0a81b895adb29b4ce                                                        |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
||                                  Output                                   ||
|+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+|
||   18:11:28 up 26 days, 22:57,  0 users,  load average: 0.01, 0.11, 0.08
  ||
|+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+|
||                                  status                                   ||
|+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+|
||  Success                                                                  ||
|+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+|
|                           ListCommandInvocations                            |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                Instancename                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  i-084f6d183997baa09                                                        |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
||                                  Output                                   ||
|+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+|
||   18:11:28 up 33 days, 23:57,  0 users,  load average: 0.75, 0.38, 0.16
  ||
|+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+|
||                                  status                                   ||
|+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+|
||  Success                                                                  ||
|+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+|
|                           ListCommandInvocations                            |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                Instancename                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  i-0d8dd2712b340630b                                                        |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
||                                  Output                                   ||
|+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+|
||   18:11:28 up 26 days, 20:22,  0 users,  load average: 0.24, 0.29, 0.27
  ||
|+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+|
||                                  status                                   ||
|+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+|
||  Success                                                                  ||
```

Expecting to get result in a proper tabular format with instance id , status and output.

Comment: Where there is a _List_ involved in the output (eg `CommandPlugins[]`), it is not possible to display the output in a simple list because there could be multiple values in the output. You could change it to `CommandPlugins[0]` to just get the _first_ value out of the array, but then you might be missing additional output.

Answer (score 0):

You won't get that out of the box with the CLI so you'll have to get clever. I don't have any resources to test, but perhaps try something like this:

```
aws ssm list-command-invocations \
--command-id "<commandid>" \
--query "CommandInvocations[].{InstanceID:InstanceId, Status:CommandPlugins[].Status[], Output:CommandPlugins[].Output[]}" --output table
```

Comment: Hi, I thnink you intended to paste a different command. That is the same command i shared.